# asp.net Setting up email

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Alas, my experience has reached an end and request help. So far I've followed the instructions from this article https://web.archive.org/web/20211016215613/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/080801-1.shtml . My only problem is It compiles fine but no email arrives. I have a feeling it's for obvious reasons which escape me.

This is my aspx.vb page.................................................................................................................

```
Imports System.Web.Mail

    Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Const ToAddress As String = "paul.ramirez@att.net"
    Dim objMM As New MailMessage("paramireze@gmail.com", ToAddress)
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
    objMM.IsBodyHtml = False
    objMM.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
    objMM.Subject = "Hello there!"
    objMM.Body = "Hi!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "How are you doing?"
    smtp.Send(objMM)
end sub
```

..........................................................................................................................................................

my aspx page contains the following ...w/o the parenthesis
(`<%@Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>`)

The web.config file is as follows(unfortunately it won't display with greater than less than symbols.

```
<configSections>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" port="25">
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configSections>
```

The people at godaddy.com told me that the only information I needed was the relayServer host name which is relay-hosting.secureserver.net and username and password weren't required.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET 1.x or ASP.NET 2.0 and beyond? If you are using 2.0+ I'd suggest using a different article as your guideline, namely http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072606-1.aspx. Also, can you be more detailed when you say "It doesn't work?" Do you mean it does not compile? Does it compile but give a Yellow Screen of Death when testing? Does it seem to send correctly, but the email never arrives? Something else?

Comment: Working on the asp.net 2.0 version instructions

Comment: Mail isn't sent on port 80. Are you sure you have the proper port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is your problem.  Change the mail server port from port 80 to port 25 in the web.config

Try using this block of code:

```
Dim objMailMessage As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage 

With objMailMessage 
    .IsBodyHtml = False 
    .From = New MailAddress("fromaddress@youremailaccount.com")   
    .To.Add("destinationaddress@whoever.com") .Subject = "Your Subject" 
    .Body = "Body Text" 
End With 

Dim objSMTPClient As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", 25) 
objSMTPClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
objSMTPClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network 
objSMTPClient.Send(objMailMessage)
```

Here is the thread and some other examples as well.  It also sounds like there is a godaddy setting somewhere, but I don't remember having to change anything on my end.

http://forums.asp.net/t/939893.aspx

Comment: Try changing the from address and checking your gmail spam filters.

Comment: I also had a problem that godaddy was delaying emails a LONG time,  a few hours sometimes...   give it a bit of time before you give up.

Comment: thanks brian, I've updated my mail object to the 2.0 version and I'm getting a inner exception of not being able to connect to the remote server, trying to figure out what that means

Comment: See my updated answer,  try that block of code.. especially the default network credentials part.

Comment: Get a blue line saying credential cache isn't declared, i'll keep working on it

Comment: you've definately solved this problem amongst others, just turned out I had more than one problem

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you cannot send email from godaddy from addresses outside of your domain.  try sending it from some registered email address on your domain.

Comment: I have one, I tried switching out my gmail account with it, but i'm getting a new error (from another change) that says "unhandled smtpexception - Failure sending mail.

Comment: after setting up the exception I'm getting the message, 'unable to connect to remote server'