# Establishing email for asp.net / vb.net

Tags: asp.net

My goal is to generate emails inside of my Asp/VB.net program. After following instructions very carefully using https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121616/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072606-1.aspx  some stackoverflow users helped me modify my class object on the asp.net page. We also revised my host/port settings in the web.config file. I still throw an exception when I try to send email which says 'Unable to connect to remote server.' After talking to the godaddy.com tech support they said I need to use the incomming server pop.secureserver.net and the outgoing server smtpout.secureserver.net. He had no further clarification. My question is, how do I set up the incomming and outgoing servers?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's time, I'm almost certain that this problem lies elsewhere. I'll post the solution once I can get my instructor to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, this is the config:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="network" from="some@address.com">
      <network host="smtpserver" port="25"></network>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

You need to change smtpserver to smtpout.secureserver.net
If that doesn't work, make sure with godaddy support that there's no "SMTP authentication" required on that server. If it's required, you can include user name/password in the  node like so:

```
<network host="smtpserver" port="25" userName="username" password="password"></network>
```

UPDATE:
according to http://help.godaddy.com/article/4219 the smtpserver should be

**relay-hosting.secureserver.net**

same is described here [asp.net Setting up email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100258/asp-net-setting-up-email/4100415) as poster below mentioned

Comment: he made it very clear that I need to set up both the outgoing and ingoing server so does that mean I should write two mailsettings?

Comment: I'm starting to think that I'm asking the wrong question that there is something else going on that i'm not seeing.

Comment: I am not sure you talked to developer support or just customer support. ASP.NET doesn't support incoming email natively.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to change anything in the web config. Just name the following code something .aspx and change the email addresses, dump it in your root directory, go to the webpage via your browser and you should recieve a mail.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        // Send Mail
        MailMessage lMail = new MailMessage();

        lMail.To = "To@somewhere.com";
        lMail.From = "Obama@thewhitehouse.com";
        lMail.Subject = "Subject";
        lMail.Body = "Body";

        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
        SmtpMail.Send(lMail);
        lMail = null;

        Response.Write("Mail sent");
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are only sending email, then i cant see why you would need anything relating to pop as that is how you would retrieve mail. Have you tried manually connecting to the smtp server from a console?

Just try and telnet to your host and send port 25 as the port and see what happens, eg

```
telnet smtpout.secureserver.net 25
```

From there you should be able to tell if you can at least get a connection, if you can try sending some mail through it. Just Google SMTP commands for how to do it

Comment: when I change the hostname from smtpout.secureserver.net to telnet smtpout.secureserver.net my thrown exception changes to the remote name could not be resolved. I've been experimenting with the telnet command site to no avail

Comment: This is just a test you have to do from command line on your own machine. This doesn't work anyways, since this is an internal SMTP server for godaddy hosting, it's not available from outside.